# Ember g-recaptcha not rendering on refresh

Tags: ember.js, recaptcha

I realize a strange behavior for the component when i'm refeshing a route or access it directly.
The component doesn't show up and this is what I have in my console :

`Uncaught TypeError: window.grecaptcha.render is not a function`

When I look under Render Performance in the Ember Inspector, the component is not rendered.
Then,  i'm going on an other route by clicking on a `{{#link-to}}`  and the component is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to verify if `window.grecaptcha` and `window.grecaptcha.render` is defined BEFORE call render function.

This starts to be a problem on this month (05/2018). My application use same code for 2 years without problem before.

More information: [Code example](https://github.com/mozilla/donate.mozilla.org/issues/1992)